# Admob test interstitial ad showing but not real ad

Tags: android, admob

Yesterday I created an interstitial ad using Admob in my Android app.

The test is showing fine, but if I put the real AdUnitId , the ad is not loading.

This is my code

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-***");


        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-**");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
               mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can check in the logcat for error code of ad retrieval, my guess it would be `error code 3 (No Fill Error)`

Comment: In my case I had not provided the information of payment in admob account, after setting up the details in my admob account ads started showing up

Comment: @hiddeneyes02, no error messages in logcat

Comment: @AnkushRawat,thank you. I have checked the payment info, and its ok

Comment: In your `AdListener() {}` implement the `onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)` method, then log the **errorCode**

Comment: @hiddeneyes02, thanks. I will try it.

Comment: @hiddeneyes02, errorCode------3

Comment: That means you need to wait few hours :)

Comment: @hiddeneyes02, ok, but I created the ads yesterday